Measurement of a surface code patch - how many detectors in Stim after the final round?
I am looking at the Stim code for a surface code patch after the final measurement. This usually has a detector that looks at multiple elements. I am struggling to understand which elements should be included in the final detector.
I understand the purpose of those detectors is to help us know if there is a measurement error on the data qubits or not. But how exactly this part works is not clear to me.
For example, for a 5x5 surface code, one has
TICK
M 2 3 4 5 6 12 13 14 15 16 22 23 24 25 26 32 33 34 35 36 42 43 44 45 46
#!pragma MARKZ(0) 2 3 4 5 6
DETECTOR(1, 0, 3) rec[-20] rec[-25] rec[-39]
DETECTOR(1, 2, 3) rec[-18] rec[-19] rec[-23] rec[-24] rec[-49]
DETECTOR(1, 4, 3) rec[-16] rec[-17] rec[-21] rec[-22] rec[-48]
DETECTOR(2, 1, 3) rec[-14] rec[-15] rec[-19] rec[-20] rec[-47]
DETECTOR(2, 3, 3) rec[-12] rec[-13] rec[-17] rec[-18] rec[-46]
DETECTOR(2, 5, 3) rec[-11] rec[-16] rec[-45]

Why is the product of the measurement outcome of some data qubits correlated with either two or four other outcomes here?

Unless I am missing something, you removed half of the detectors, right?

Yes, I just showed a few lines of detectors - you are correct that there are more!

In this last round, you measure the 25 data qubits in the $Z$ basis. The measurement outcomes are stored in the list rec. rec[-1] is the measurement outcome of the data qubit labelled 46 and rec[-25] corresponds to the measurement outcome of data qubit 2. This last measurement round covers the last 25 elements of rec, so indices [-25;-1].
The detectors are all ensuring the product of two (or four) measurement outcomes of the data qubit in the last round is the same as one measurement outcome of a previous round. For each line of detector, only one rec index is outside the [-25;-1] range.
The two (or four) data qubit measurement outcomes of each line corresponds to one stabilizer of the surface code. Indeed, in the rotated surface code the $Z$ stabilizers are of weight 2 or 4. The last measurement outcome of each detector line should correspond to the previous measurement of this stabilizer, which presumably have been done through an ancilla qubit earlier in a previous round. You can check that the data qubits entangled with the ancilla measured in the previous round rec[-39] for example are data qubit 12 (-20) and 2 (-25).
The reason why this is possible is that in the last round, you won't be needing the data qubits anymore, so you can save an ancilla entanglement and the potential errors that go with it. The product of the measurement outcomes of the data qubits that form a stabilizer corresponds to the measurement outcome of this stabilizer (the measurement outcome is reconstructed from the data qubits).


the purpose of those detectors is to help us know if there is a measurement error on the data qubits or not.

Not exactly. From the decoding point of view, this is necessary as you need to be sure that no measurement errors happened in the last round. By measuring directly the data qubits, a measurement error will be undistinguishable from a regular $X$ error happening on the qubit and will be treated as such by the decoder.

About the last part, isn't a Z measurement error the same thing as X error on qubit followed by a faithful Z measurement? I think I didn't get the last point but otherwise, you answered my question. Thank you!

Yes, indeed. A decoder will match error defects (ie triggered detectors) by pairs. When a measurement error happens, the two defects are paired between two different rounds. If it happened on the last round, you wouldn't be able to pair it. When you measure directly the data qubits and reconstruct the stabilizer measurement outcomes, a faulty measurement of one qubit will still have a repercussion on two neighboring stabilizers as the same faulty measurement is used to reconstructed both measurement outcomes. So the decoder will succeed.
